# What is an example of an invertible matrix, A, that has more than one solution to Ax=b?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that the invertibility theorem tells us that Ax=b has at least one solution for every b in R^n .  I'm also aware that Ax=0 will have ONLY the trivial solution.

What is an example of an invertible matrix, A where there is more than one solution for a particular b?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confused. If $A$ is invertible, then $Ax=b$ has the unique solution $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  But, in countless sources, e.g. [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m22s07/public_html/invertmatrixthm.pdf), I've seen it written that there is "at least one solution" for every b.  Am I misunderstanding them, or is it incorrect?

Comment: The reason that link you provided says that a square matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if "$Ax=b$ has at least one solution for all $b$" is that "it has at least one" is a slightly easier condition to check than "it has one and only one."   It turns out that if you show it has _at least one solution for all $b$_, then that implies it has one and only one.

Comment: The standard proof goes something like this:  Suppose $Ax=b$ has at least one solution for all $b$.  Let $e_i$ be the $i$th column of the identity matrix and let $r_i$ be a vector that satisfies $Ar_i=e_i$ (such an $r_i$ exists by the fact $Ax=b$ has a solution for all $b$).  Then define $C = [r_1 r_2 \cdots r_N]$.  So $C$ is a square matrix such that $AC=I$, and this is another property that eventually implies invertibility (which eventually implies $Ax=b$ has at most one solution for all $b$). Since it has both "at least one" and "at most one," we conclude it has "one and only one."

Comment: So, the source I cited seems like it makes the statement too general.  There will never be anything but exactly one solution to Ax=b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written isn't actually quite right. If $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1}$ exists, and thus
$$ Ax = b \iff A^{-1}b = A^{-1}Ax = x.$$
Thus this is the only solution, and it always exists. (Note that $b = 0$ implies $x=0$.)

If $A$ is not invertible, then $Ax = b$ may have no solutions, an exact solution ($x^*$) or an uncountably large family of solutions given by
$$x = x^* + \lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots \lambda_r v_r,$$
for vectors $v_1,...,v_r$. (So the solution space then has dimension $r$, if it exists.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got confused. If $A$ is invertible, then $Ax = b \implies x = A^{-1}b$, and so $x$ is unique and determined by the expression $A^{-1}b$. Now consider: $$\begin{cases} x-y = 0 \\ 2x-2y = 0\end{cases}$$Your matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$ is not invertible and the system has the solution set $\{ (x,x) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \in \Bbb R \}$.